# Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a usercontrol that I would like to animate at certain times.  I add two of those user controls to a window.  I use a button in that window to start the animation.  One of the usercontrols works just fine.  The second one gives me the Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance error.  I don't get this at all!  Why would one work and not the other? I was reading about needed a converter - but I could not get that to work at all.  I left the code in here just in case I do need it.  Thank you for any help you can give me on this.  I am new to WPF so I may be doing some dumb stuff here - please forgive me.  Here is my code for the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="colorCompButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:UserControlTests"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:UserControlTests"

         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="179" Width="317">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="sb2" RepeatBehavior="Forever" x:Name="thisone">

        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="badge1" 
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="Red" To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=BadgeColor}" 
      Duration="0:0:1" />

    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0,0,10,10">

    <Rectangle x:Name="rect"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259" x:FieldModifier="public"  Fill ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=RectColor}"/>
    <Image x:Name="image" Height="87" Margin="10,10,63,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:FieldModifier="public" Source ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ImageSource}"/>


    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="0,102,10,38" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=TxtBoxValue}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Padding="3"/>

    <Grid Margin="222,81,0,0" x:Name="NumberIMG" Height="78" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="85" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=BadgeVisibile}" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Maroon" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="120" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=BadgeColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="76"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" x:Name="badge1" x:FieldModifier="public"></Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="black" Margin="2,2,0,0" BorderThickness="3" Opacity=".5" CornerRadius="120"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"></Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="120"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78">
            <Label x:Name="resCount" Content="46" FontSize="25"  Foreground="White"  HorizontalContentAlignment="center" VerticalContentAlignment="center" Margin="0,0,-3,-3"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And the code behind for that control:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Public Class colorCompButton
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
'Public Shared Sub SetImage(obj As DependencyObject, value As ImageSource)
'    obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value)
'End Sub
'Public Shared Function GetImage(obj As DependencyObject) As ImageSource
'    Return DirectCast(obj.GetValue(ImageProperty), ImageSource)
'End Function


Shared Sub New()
    'register attached dependency property

    Dim metadata = New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DirectCast(Nothing, ImageSource))
    'ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", GetType(ImageSource), GetType(colorCompButton), metadata)
End Sub


Public Shared ReadOnly BadgeVisibileProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BadgeVisibile", GetType(Visibility), GetType(colorCompButton), New PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible))

Public Property BadgeVisibile() As Visibility
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(BadgeVisibileProperty), Visibility)
    End Get
    Set(value As Visibility)
        SetValue(BadgeVisibileProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly BadgeColorProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BadgeColor", GetType(Brush), GetType(colorCompButton), New PropertyMetadata(New SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)))
Public Property BadgeColor() As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(BadgeColorProperty), SolidColorBrush)
    End Get
    Set(value As SolidColorBrush)
        SetValue(BadgeColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly buttonColorProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("buttonColor", GetType(Brush), GetType(colorCompButton), New PropertyMetadata(New SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)))
Public Property buttonColor() As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(buttonColorProperty), SolidColorBrush)
    End Get
    Set(value As SolidColorBrush)
        SetValue(buttonColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Public Shared ReadOnly ImageSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", GetType(BitmapSource), GetType(colorCompButton))
Public Property ImageSource() As ImageSource
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ImageSourceProperty), ImageSource)
    End Get
    Set(value As ImageSource)
        SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Public Shared ReadOnly RectColorProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RectColor", GetType(Brush), GetType(colorCompButton), New PropertyMetadata(New SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)))
Public Property RectColor() As SolidColorBrush
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(RectColorProperty), SolidColorBrush)
    End Get
    Set(value As SolidColorBrush)
        SetValue(RectColorProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared TxtBoxValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("txtBoxValue", GetType([String]), GetType(colorCompButton))
Public Property TxtBoxValue() As [String]
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(TxtBoxValueProperty), [String])
    End Get
    Set(value As [String])
        SetValue(TxtBoxValueProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Public Sub StartLeafUp()
    Dim sb As Storyboard = TryCast(Me.Resources("sb2"), Storyboard)
    sb.Begin()
End Sub

Public Sub StartLeafDown()
    Dim sb As Storyboard = TryCast(Me.Resources("sb2"), Storyboard)
    sb.Stop()
End Sub
End Class
Friend Class MyCloneConverter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    If TypeOf value Is Freezable Then
        value = TryCast(value, Freezable).Clone()
    End If

    Return value
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotSupportedException()
End Function
End Class
```

Main window and code behind:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlTests" x:Class="MainWindow"
Title="MainWindow" Height="437" Width="1057">

<Grid>

    <local:colorCompButton x:Name="color" Margin="201,62,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BadgeColor="#FF833E1D" buttonColor="Sienna" RectColor="Sienna" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/deviation.png" TxtBoxValue="I WORK"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="WORKS FINE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,262,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Height="53"/>

    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="DOES NOT WORK!!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="534,262,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" Height="53"/>
    <local:colorCompButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="534,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BadgeColor="Indigo" RectColor="IndianRed" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/deviation.png" TxtBoxValue="I WON'T WORK" x:Name="res"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="EXACT SAME CONTROLS.  WHY WILL THIS NOT WORK??" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="375,365,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Class MainWindow

Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    color.StartLeafUp()


End Sub

Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    res.StartLeafUp()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but I solved this on my own by adding another border, setting it's background to transparent and animating it instead of the first border.  This seems more like a hack than a solution, but it works.  I am still willing to hear a real solution - if anyone has one.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for me was that I was doing this:

```
Background="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton, Path=Background}"
```

Rather than this:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

On a control that I was animating inside a control template.

It seems like you have the same mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error/problem while trying to animate TextBlock Foreground property.

One workaround is to create a Color type DependencyProperty and set it as the target for color animation. Then, for example, bind a TextBlock Foreground property to the DependencyProperty of the hosting UserControl (or Window) and use a converter to create a Brush from the Color.

Here is an example for the flashing TextBlock that I named SpectrumTextBlock, that starts animation when the control is loaded:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Common.SpectrumTextBlock"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Common"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="spectrumTextBlock">

<UserControl.Resources>

    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="colorToBrushConverter"/>

    <Storyboard x:Key="spectrumStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(EffectColor)" Storyboard.TargetName="spectrumTextBlock">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="Red"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Orange"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Yellow"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Green"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Cyan"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Blue"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="Violet"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="TEST TEXT" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=spectrumTextBlock, Path=EffectColor, Converter={StaticResource colorToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

and CS file of this control that includes the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace Common
{
public partial class SpectrumTextBlock : UserControl
{
    private Storyboard _effestStoryboard;

    public Color EffectColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(EffectColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EffectColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EffectColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EffectColor", typeof(Color), typeof(SpectrumTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(SystemColors.ControlTextColor));

    public SpectrumTextBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += SpectrumTextBlock_Loaded;
    }

    private void SpectrumTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _effestStoryboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("spectrumStoryboard");
        _effestStoryboard.Begin();
    }
}

internal class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Another workaround would be to use a 0px size (not visible) Rectangle and animate the Fill property, and then bind TextBlock Foreground property to the Fill property of the Rectangle. But the first DependencyProperty workaround looks less "hacky".

Answer (score 1):

Any one who face the issue:

> Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance

Adding `[VisualState x:Name="Normal"]` Solved the issue.

Below code is an example:

XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Border x:Name="borderIn" 
                        CornerRadius="0">
                    <Label>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Label>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="borderIn" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="LightBlue" Storyboard.TargetName="borderIn" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="borderIn" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="borderIn" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="borderIn" Value="LightCyan" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="borderIn" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope this solution help those who face same issue